# External HDD gets recognized under Linux Mint but not under Windows 8

Tags: linux, windows-8, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a system with Windows 8. I had the problem, that whenever I plugged in my external hard drive, the HDD booted up and then, after 5 seconds shut down again. At first I thought this would be a HDD problem, but after testing again under Linux, where the External HDD gets recognized without any problems and is accessable and is always turned on, I doubt that it's an HDD error

Also, in the BIOS, my external hdd is listed there. As soon as Windows gets started, it shuts down

Here is a screen of the BIOS where it is listed
[image: Here is a screen of the BIOS where it is listed]

What did I try out?

```
Plugging in the external HDD in a different USB Port
Trying a "different" (Linux Mint) system
```

Where did I check that the HDD doesn't get recognized?

```
Explorer
Driver Manager
Disk Management Utility
```

The external HDD is nowhere listed, but gets recognized by the BIOS and also on Linux without problems. On Windows, however, it immedieatly shuts itself down!

I just checked under linux, the filesystem is `fuseblk`
When googling it, it returns me that fuseblk is `NTFS`.

The problem is, that the external HDD worked all the time without any problems. It just recently happened that Windows doesn't recognize it anymore.
I downloaded the software of seagate for external hdds SeaTools and even the software doesn't find the external hdd. I don't get it...

I am at work right now, so I will try out the suggestions once I'm home again! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 still has some issues with the USB 3.0 drivers. If you are using a USB 3.0 port try using USB 2.0 one. Also try to turn off fast startup as sometimes it doesn't load all the drivers correctly. 
You can also try reinstalling the USB controller drivers.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. I used both USB 3.0 and USB 2.0. None of them worked. Fast boot is already offline. 

How do I reinstall them? In the device manager under usb devices?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial, I think this would help  http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/usb-drive-or-flash-problems-how-to-cleanup-and-remove-old-usb-storage-drivers.145884/